# Problem with civicrm tab in webform

Tags: webform-civicrm

Hello everyone i've a very weird problem. All tutorials show webform civicrm integration installation normaly and easyly done. I've done installation but in webform i do not see the civicrm tab displayed. Do anybody know what happened ?
I only have these tabs [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solve the problem by doing this:
1- desable properly webform module and uninstall it.
2- desable properly webform civicrm integration and uninstall it.
And i reisntall the both module and flush all caches. And i have the civicrm tab now

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 2):

Is the webform_civicrm module enabled as well as being installed?  Go to your Modules page in Drupal (`/admin/modules`) and check it is enabled.

Also trying flushing the Drupal caches (`/admin/config/development/performance`)

Comment: Thanks sir for your answer. Yes the module webfor civicrm integration is well enabled. I also purge all my cache but problem still here.

Comment: If the Webform and webform_civicrm modules are BOTH enabled then you will see a CiviCRM tab to the right of Devel i expect

Comment: Yes that is the normal behaviour but i don't know the reason i don't see civicrm tab within webform.I've flushed drupal an civicrm caches but always the same. Any help will be very appreciate. And i'm using drupal 7 - civicrm 5.16.2